# Using the paperclipdropbox gem for storage of uploads

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, rubygems, paperclip, dropbox

I have a Rails app that needs to store resumes for job applications. Locally, the attachment works fine using the Paperclip plugin. I would like to store them on production using the paperclipdropbox gem. I did the following :

1) set up paperclip for attachment following the document on github

2) ran the command for installing the dropbox gem, on which paperclipdropbox

```
gem install dropbox
```

3) set up paperclipdropbox as per https://github.com/dripster82/paperclipdropbox#readme
My paperclipdropbox.yml file looks like that

```
development:
  dropbox_key: email_for_dropbox_account
  dropbox_secret: password_for_dropboxaccount
production:
  dropbox_key: email_for_dropbox_account
  dropbox_secret: password_for_dropboxaccount
```

After running

```
rake paperclipdropbox:authorize
```

I get the following error :

```
C:\Sites\appname>rake paperclipdropbox:authorize  --trace
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'paperclipdropbox:authorize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task_
manager.rb:49:in `[]'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/appli
cation.rb:115:in `invoke_task'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/appli
cation.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/appli
cation.rb:94:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/appli
cation.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/appli
cation.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/appli
cation.rb:88:in `top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/appli
cation.rb:66:in `block in run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/appli
cation.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/appli
cation.rb:63:in `run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in
 `'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/bin/rake:19:in `load'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/bin/rake:19:in `'
```

I didn't find much documentation online unfortunately. Any idea of what may be causing the problem ? Do you have any other free alternatives for storage ?

Comment: If you run `rake -T`, does `paperclipdropbox:authorize` shows up there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might have installed the gems, but didn't defined them in your `Gemfile`. Make sure that you have `paperclip`, `dropbox`, `paperclip-dropbox` gem in your Gemfile.

```
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'dropbox'
gem 'paperclipdropbox'
```

then run `bundle install`, and try to run that rake task again. This is because by default Bundler would isolate and make only gems that in your `Gemfile` to be visible to your Rails application.

Answer (score 0):

You must create the project in dropbox. [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers) you have the link.

after use `rake paperclipdropbox:authorize`